# Reducing width of subplots?

Tags: r, raster

I have a multipanel plot I am making, and I want to try to make the figures themselves as large as possible and as close to each other as possible.  The closest I have come is with this code:

```
library(raster)
library(colorRamps)
library(Cairo)

Cairo(file = "C:\\plot.png", type = "png", units = "in", width = 10, height = 8, pointsize = 10, dpi = 600)
opar = par(mfrow=c(2, 2), mar = c(0,0,2,0), oma = c(0,0,0,0))

ras_1 = raster("F:\\ras_1.tif")
ras_2 = raster("F:\\ras_2.tif")
ras_3 = raster("F:\\ras_3.tif")
ras_4 = raster("F:\\ras_4.tif")

xlim = c(616266.1, 646613.6)
ylim = c(5130538, 5160481)

plot(ras_1, col = rev(blue2red(11)), axes=F, legend=F)
title(main = 'Time Series', line = 0.6, adj = 0.45)

plot(ras_2, col = rev(blue2red(11)), axes=F, legend=F)
title(main = 'Early Season', line = 0.6, adj = 0.45)

plot(ras_3, col = rev(blue2red(11)), axes=F, legend=F)
title(main = 'Peak Summer', line = 0.6, adj = 0.45)

plot(ras_4, col = rev(blue2red(11)), axes=F, legend=F)
title(main = 'Late Season', line = 0.6, adj = 0.45)
plot(ras_4, legend.only=TRUE, col = rev(blue2red(11)), legend.width = 1, legend.shrink=0.75, smallplot = c(0.74,0.79, 0.26, 0.60)))


dev.off()
```

which gives me:

[image]

The height of each subplot is good to me as all of the available space is being used, but what I would like to do is reduce the width of the frames on each subplot so that they are as close the plotted data as possible, and then have the two plots on the left and right be as close to each other as possible (I don't want white space in the middle of the plot).  I thought I was doing this with `oma` and `mar` but this seems to be an issue with the size of each subplot themselves.

Comment: You are likely being limited by aspect ratio. If you change the dimensions of the overall image to be closer to the aspect ratio of the individual images, it may turn out better.

Comment: Thank you, setting `asp = 0.8` takes up some of the middle space, although it does look a bit stretched out.  Better than nothing though.